# Laravel 429 too many requests - other way to refresh time from database

Tags: php, laravel, http, throttling

I have application in `Angular 11` and `Laravel`.
I need display time status every second in html in `Angular`. Now I have method:

```
this.uptimeService.getUptimeByUserForToday(userid, newDateNow).subscribe(res => {
    if (res.status === 'Ok') {    
        if (res.item != null) {
            this.currentUptimeDTO = res.item;
        }
    }
});
```

The request is send over `Http` every second. I get error `429, too many request`. I can set in `app/Http/Kernel.php` throttle value:

```
'api' => [
    'throttle:60,1',
],
```

What is the case when will be a lot of users? This is the only way to refresh time every second on the view in `Angular`?
In C# there is a `SignalR` that sends a request on a lower layer than `Http` and packets are smaller than `Http` packets.
In `Laravel (PHP)` there is only an `Http` request?

Comment: "lower layer than Http" ? do you mean another protocol ? " I need display time status every second" describe your need a bit more. what do you mean by "time status" ?
BTW, you can use SignalR in PHP too, or use socket.io or  Laravel Echo. All of them use the protocol WebSocket to communicate.

Comment: I need to display uptime every second. Your answer is what I wanted know, WebSocket will be right solution, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Websocket` works fine, changing `throttle` parameter in config in `Laravel` didn't help.
Now I have client in `Angular` and `ws server` written in `Node` and `Typescript` that is completely bypassess `Laravel api`

Comment: have you tested ws on a number of users say 300 or 500 users? how is the performance?